# How to read table pasted in outlook message body using vba?

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to read table of data as in picure using vba. I used **Msg.Body** to read the body text but actually i need to find first row as header and rest as data field and update DBMS table accordingly.So is it possible to read the table as I would in excel?
[image: Outlook]

Comment: What is the mail body format?  HTML, rich text ?  What is the source of the table - was it pasted in from Word/Excel ?

Comment: Can you split the email body using Split(Msg.Body, vbCrLf)? The first array token will be the header. Everything from LBound(Split(Msg.Body, vbCrLf))+1 to UBound() will be the data.

Comment: @TimWilliams yes it was pasted from excel !!!

Comment: @JP. How do I know which part is a table and move through rows and columns ? I am stuck!!

Comment: Have you tried my answer yet?

Comment: @JP yes but it tokenizes all string i.e. "Dear all" part too! So I am trying to build a template and add your solution to end. I am confused how to find the end of table.And I am confused that numberofColumns = Len(rows(0)) - Len(Replace(rows(0), Chr(9), "")) always gives a 0. Why have you replaced tab with a "".

Comment: If there is other text in the body of the email, it will need to be removed first. Only you know what the header values are, so only you know where to start parsing.

Comment: Regarding tab replacement, that is how to count the number of columns in the table. When you paste from Excel into Outlook, then tokenize the row into an array, the row contains Chr(9), that is how you figure out the column count.

Comment: @JP. It works in main folder Inbox!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sample procedure should help. I recreated your table in Excel, pasted it into an Outlook email and sent it to myself. Then I used this procedure to read the "cell" values.

```
Sub GetLines()

Dim msg As Outlook.mailItem
Dim rows As Variant
Dim numberofColumns As Long
Dim numberofRows As Long
Dim headerValues As Variant
Dim headerRow() As String
Dim data() As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

' get currently selected email
Set msg = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)

' tokenize each line of the email
rows = Split(msg.Body, vbCrLf)

' calculate array size
numberofColumns = Len(rows(0)) - Len(Replace(rows(0), Chr(9), ""))
numberofRows = UBound(rows) + 1

' put header row into array
ReDim headerRow(1 To numberofColumns)
headerValues = Split(rows(0), Chr(9))

For i = 1 To numberofColumns
  headerRow(i) = Trim$(headerValues(i - 1))
Next i

' calculate data array size
numberofRows = numberofRows - 1

' put data into array
ReDim data(1 To numberofRows, 1 To numberofColumns)

  For i = 1 To numberofRows
    For j = 1 To numberofColumns
      data(i, j) = Trim$(Split(rows(i), Chr(9))(j - 1))
    Next j
  Next i

End Sub
```

First we tokenize each line of the email into an array. We calculate the array size, then create an array to hold just the first line of the table (the "header").

Then we subtract one from the row count because we are going to skip the header row. We then loop through each row, split it and loop through its values, assigning them to our 2D array as we go.

In the end, the variable "headerRow" can be iterated to retrieve the field values you want to use for your DBMS. The variable "data" contains only the values corresponding to each field. So headerRow(1) and data(n,1) should correspond to the values in the first column of your table.