# Copy table in email to Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to create some code that will copy the body of an email into a new Excel spreadsheet. I have this code:

```
Public Sub ExportToExcel1()

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim objSearchFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim mai As MailItem

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Hold Info")
Set objSearchFolder = Inbox

i = 0
For Each item In Inbox.Items
    item.Display
    item.Body.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkb As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' New Excel.Application
    Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Selection.Paste False, False, False
Next 

End Sub
```

It keeps giving me an error at `item.Body.Select` and I have no clue why. It may have something to do with the fact that the email I am trying to copy is nothing but tables that were generated in Oracle, but I have no clue.

Comment: `item.Body` returns a String value - that has no `Copy` method. You should also check the type of the item forst to ensure it's not some other non-mail type (eg. calendar item).  What format are the mails you want to copy from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read table pasted in outlook message body using vba?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061350/how-to-read-table-pasted-in-outlook-message-body-using-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Clipboard directly rather than trying to select and copy. If you have a userform in your project, you already have this reference set. If not, set a reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library.  Then use a DataObject to put some text into the Clipboard.

```
Public Sub ExportToExcel1()

    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Object
    Dim doClip As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim xlApp As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkb As Object

    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Hold Info")
    Set doClip = New MSForms.DataObject

    For Each item In Inbox.Items
        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
            doClip.SetText item.Body
            doClip.PutInClipboard

            Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") ' New Excel.Application
            xlApp.Visible = True
            Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
            xlWkb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial "Text"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

A couple of points to consider. When you use the Clipboard in this fashion, you're using the Windows Clipboard, not the Office Clipboard. The Windows Clipboard doesn't recognize Office specific Clipboard formats, so you lose a little in translation.

Pasting from the Clipboard has some advantages. But if you want complete control of how your data shows up in Excel, then read the Body into a string, parse the string for the data you want, and write the specific data to the cells you want.