# VBA Error 91: Object Variable not set

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the code below to read the table from outlook email. But I'm getting error at the line `ActiveInspector.WordEditor`.

```
    Set doc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
    lngRows = tbl.Rows.Count
    lngColumns = tbl.Columns.Count
```

I've marked the `Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library` in the references as well. Can someone help?

I'm trying to solve the problem I mentioned here:

[Read a table in outlook mail using macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38254754/read-a-table-in-outlook-mail-using-macro/38257541#38257541)

Comment: How did you declare your variables -Try `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor`

Comment: Tried that. Didn't worked. Same error

Comment: if I understand correctly - you are coping data from email body and saving it to where? `Excel file` or `csv file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1) change to either starting with an open mailitem or

```
Sub inspWord()

    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table

    Dim lngRows As Long
    Dim lngColumns As Long

    ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).Display
    Set doc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(1)
    lngRows = tbl.Rows.count
    lngColumns = tbl.Columns.count

End Sub
```

Comment: This code is using the opened word documents. I need to access the Outlook mail. I've tried replacing like this: Dim doc as Outlook.MailItem. Still the error remains same

Comment: The code in the answer uses the Word editor in Outlook. Word is not involved.